# Why didn't The Hound leave Arya Stark at The Eyrie?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Even though they learned of the death of her aunt, surely there would still be someone there that could pay a small ransom. Both The Hound & Arya, and Sansa & Lord Baelish would recognize each other. At the very least, Arya would be safe, and The Hound would no longer need to feed or protect her. Later, The Hound told Brienne of Tarth that there is no safe place left for Arya, so why would he take her away from The Eyrie? They could have at least gotten food or rest, which would allow Arya to meet her sister Sansa, and likely cause her to stay for good. I'm referring to the TV show.

[image: bloody gate]

[image: hound and arya at bloody gate castle eyrie]

Comment: How would The Hound know that he or Arya would be allowed, let alone safe within the Eyrie?

Answer (score 5):

There are two reasons:

- Nobody would recognize Arya if they went there. Arya never met someone from the Vale recently, so nobody could identify her. And it wasn't clear whether they would pay.
- The bandits around the Vale have grown very strong. So during the journey it would be harder for him to protect her. [SoS65](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/A_Storm_of_Swords-Chapter_65)

Furthermore, he doesn't go to the Riverlands and tries to sell her off there, because it was sieged at the time, so nobody could be distracted by a ransom.

Comment: ? Sansa and Lord Bailish would recognize Arya, and Arya would recognize them. ? They were at the Bloody Gates when Arya learned of her aunt's death and laughed, and it was only a few steps more to the castle.

Comment: @Chloe nobody knew it was Sansa. They all thought she was a niece or something of Petyr. As for Petyr, he wasn't the most trustworthy and also, he only met her once at the tournament of the Hand, so mistaking her is completely in the realm of the possible.

Comment: Arya and Sansa would recognize each other, no matter which name they go by. Sansa also told the council her real name when Lord Bailish was being questioned about the Lady's (Arya's aunt's) death.

Comment: @Chloe but the hound doesn't know that this is Sansa. So this is another reason why he doesn't go there. The main reason still being the bandits.

Comment: I'm referring to the TV show. They are within site of the castle. No bandits near.

Comment: @Chloe ok, then you should state this, because in the book, the hound decides to not go to the eyrie as you can see in the synopsis of chapter 65 of A Storm of Swords.

Comment: Just saw this episode recently -- even in the show nobody knew Sansa was at the Eyrie, IIRC, so the Hound and Arya had no way of knowing Arya would be recognised (dramatic irony).

Comment: Did the Hound and Arya even know that Petyr was at the Eyrie?

Comment: @Namfuak The only reason the Hound and Arya could have known Petyr was at the Eyrie would be if they had somehow heard about Petyr's recent nuptials. If I'm remembering events correctly, I believe even the  Lannister network of eyes-and-ears was slow catching rumors of Petyr's whereabouts, so I doubt Hound & Pup managed to stumble upon this kind of info while bumbling along the countryside. :)

Comment: @DavidH That's what I figured, so all the discussion of whether they thought Petry would pay is moot, since they didn't think he was there in the first place.